# Load C++ Class Library from C# (64 bit)

Tags: c#, c++, windows, 32bit-64bit, badimageformatexception

I have a C++ Class Library and an Windows application in C# using the library.

It works great on 32-bit Windows, but not on 64-bit Windows - `BadImageFormatException` occured.

I tried to change the platform of the C++ Class Library, however it can not changed to WIN64 from WIN32.

I think that one of the following questions can solve this problem.

1. Is there a way to convert WIN32 Library to WIN64 Library?
2. Is there another way to call C++ function on C# without using C++ Library?
3. Is it possible to load WIN32 Library in 64 bit application?

Comment: Unless you have a specific need to use the 64-bit CLR, you can compile to 32-bit instead of AnyCPU. WOW does a pretty good job running 32-bit apps on x64 Windows.

Comment: How are you calling the C++ library from your C# code? Have you looked at [PInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(v=vs.71).aspx)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to convert WIN32 Library to WIN64 Library?

Rebuild (recompile) the library as a 64-bit library.

> Is it possible to load WIN32 Library in 64 bit application?

No. From [Programming Guide for 64-bit Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384249.aspx):

> ... 32-bit processes cannot load 64-bit DLLs for execution, and 64-bit processes cannot load 32-bit DLLs for execution.

Comment: How to rebuild the library as a 64-bit library?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and the platform of the library can not be changed from Win32.